# How to get stringstream to treat uint8_t as a number not a character?

Tags: stringstream

I have this code and wondering if it's possible to have stringstream to treat uint8_t as a number not a character?

```
uint8_t s;
std::stringstream sstream( "255" );
sstream >> s;
std::cout << s << " equals 50/'2' not 255 " << std::endl;
```

s should be 255 not 50/'2'

Comment: So the only solution is to use uint16_t?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using std::stringstream in order to convert uint8_t to string, then you can use [std::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) instead. Allowed in c++11 only.

### C++11 Feature

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
uint8_t value = 7;
std::cout << std::to_string(value) << std::endl;
// Output is "7"
```

Comment: Please provide some examples or more explanation so that the asker can understand you better.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the reverse conversion: string to uint8_t.

Comment: I think it's implementation dependent I have one host that std::to_string(uint8_t)  returns char not value

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an `int`:

```
std::cout << (int)s << " equals 2 not 255 " << std::endl;
```